# How to deploy Maven project as jar file to Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jar

I am using eclipse IDE mars version.In that I have a maven project.I need to deploy the maven project as jar file in my tomcat's deploy path when I publish the tomcat. But when I publish the tomcat the maven project is deployed as folder where it contains class files,META_INF and WEB_INF folders.

How to pack the maven project as jar when I publish the tomcat?

I need to move the deployed jars from deploy path to lib folder of tomcat.

Please anyone suggest me how to get it done.
Thanks.

Comment: java web applications are distributed as 'war' files

Comment: Is your folder really names `WEB_INF` and not `WEB-INF` also for `META_INF` should be `META-INF`?

Comment: No.It is named as WEB-INF and META-INF only.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `packaging` tag in you pom.xml is set to `war`

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Comment: packaging tag in my pom.xml is set to "jar". Since I need to deploy the project as "jar". Setting the packaging tag as "war" also deploys the project as folder in my deploy path.